# Rename the "Enter your address to view shipping options" in WooCommerce checkout page

Tags: php

I want to rename the text that says "Enter your address to view shipping options." in the WooCommerce checkout page right at the bottom where the "Your Order" section was located.

I'm using this code to do it, and it works but It also give a warning  "array_ky_exist(): The first argument should be either a string or an integer in this line if( array_key_exists( $translation, $custom_text ) )"

```
add_filter('gettext', 'Behrooz_woo_translations', 20, 3);
add_filter('ngettext', 'Behrooz_woo_translations', 20, 3);
function Behrooz_woo_translations( $translation, $text, $domain ) {
    
// Put your custom text here in a key => value pair
$custom_text = array(
    'Enter your address to view shipping options.' => 'This is the text that you want to     replace with the original Text.',
);

if( array_key_exists( $translation, $custom_text ) ) {
    $translation = $custom_text[$translation];
}
return $translation;
}
```